# UnityEngine.UI not recognized by vs code and vs community

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i updated my unity to 2021.2.3f1, and vs code and vs community doesn't recognize UnityEngine.UI, i've tried: reinstalling Unity Hub, reinstalling vs code and vs community, regenerating project files, changing stuff in manifest.json (in packages folder), restarting OmniSharp. Nothing worked. It works in the older versions of unity. Also, TMPro doesn't work either. [using UnityEngine.UI not being recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvDk.png)

Comment: What happens when you create a new unity project?

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED

I fixed it by changing the "Visual Studio Code Editor" package version to 1.2.5 in the unity package manager.